# Facebook Client-Side Authentication Example - Adding Scope

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook JS SDK to do Client-Side Authentication per there example located [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));

      // Init the SDK upon load
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel', // Path to your Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
            FB.api('/me', function(me){
              if (me.name) {
                document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
              }
            })
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
          }
        });

        // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
        document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
          FB.login();
        });
        document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
          FB.logout();
        }); 
      } 
    </script>

    <h1>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</h1>
      <div id="auth-status">
        <div id="auth-loggedout">
          <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display:none">
          Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>  
        (<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

What I haven't been able to figure out in my mucking around is how to add, to this code, the scope parameter to request access to the email address.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

I've seen this code located in the documentation

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

I guess I'm not sure how to incorporate that into this existing code though because it's not working

```
document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
              FB.login();
            });
```

If anyone can update the above line to incorporate the extra scope parameter I'm eager to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution for you.  Just add those parameters to the `FB.login()` function.

```
 FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'email'});
```

If you don't need to handle the login response then just provide an empty function.

Comment: Updated my original post.  I've seen that code, but was unable to incorporate it successfully.

Comment: Well no errors, clicking the Login link just didn't do anything at all.  Since in the initial code sample FB.login() doesn't do any of the response handling I don't think I updated it properly with the code sample you provided since it also takes the response function in addition to the scope parameter.

Comment: You can simply ignore the callback... Put an empty function even.   The code also might not do anything because you are already logged in...

Comment: When I tried same code, I am still getting email undefined. My code is same given in facebook sample code https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/ except that I have change Fb.login with code you have provided.

I have also set permission to get email id, but when I login to the app for the first, facebook is not asking permission to share email id. So perhaps problem is with permissions. I have added email as required permission under user & friend permissions. Any thing else I am missing?